# Where is the UK Coronavirus legislation limiting movement?

Tags: criminal-law, united-kingdom, covid-19

The government has issued guidelines saying that we must stay inside.  I understand this has now passed into law.  Can anyone please point me to a copy of the legislation, and point out which sections are the relevant ones?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it simply asks for a link to a copy of the law and for someone to indicate which sections OP is curious about.  This is not a question about the law.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Coronavirus Act 2020](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2020/7/contents/enacted).  Specifically [Schedule 21](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2020/7/schedule/21/enacted) which relates to control of potentially infectious persons and [Schedule 22](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2020/7/schedule/22/enacted) which limits gatherings and other aspects.

[The Health Protection (Coronavirus, Restrictions) (England) Regulations 2020](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2020/350/contents/made).  Specifically [Regulation 6](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2020/350/regulation/6/made), which relates to restriction on movement.

Comment: Note that the Regulations mentioned in this answer are made under the Public Health (Control of Disease) Act 1984, not the Coronavirus Act.